# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Elmah.MVC issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, assemblies, elmah.mvc

Locally - my MVC 4, asp.net, c# app runs fine on IIS 8 / Windows 8.

When deployed to Windows Server 2008, I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

and

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap.Initialize() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +12881963
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +12881672
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +240
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881108
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12722297
```

This happens if I select 'Only files needed to run this application' from the 'Items to deploy' drop down in project properties/package/publish web.

If I select 'all files in this project' it works fine.

I guess Elmah is reliant on an older version of MVC or something - how can I fix this without having to upload all the files?

Whats the best way to problem solve situations like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had this exact same issue using MVC4 with Ninject built for .Net 4.5

To fix this i had to add a binding redirect to my Web.config file:
(at the end of the file, just before the `</configuration>` tag)

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

This forces the web server to use `System.Web.Mvc 4.0.0.0` instead of an older version.

Comment: With asp.net mvc 5 version replace 2.0.0.0 with 3.0.0.0 - replace 4.0.0.0 with 5.0.0.0

Comment: But why does this happen? I have the same problem without NInject and for the life of me I can't figure out which assembly is referencing v3! FusionLogs show that "someone" is requesting it but Calling Assembly is Unknown. I really really wanna know why.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependentAssembly>
            ***<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0"*** newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Check correct versions are there

Answer (score 0):

> There are some procedures using to fix the issue and if the binding redirect in `web.config` does not solve the problem, you can try the following steps to fix it:

**1)** In Visual Studio Solution Explorer tree right-click References under your web project and select Manage NuGet Packages.

**2)** Go to Browse tab and select `nuget.org` as Package source.

**3)** Search and install the following packages: `Ninject`, `Ninject.Web.Common` and `Ninject.MVC5`.

It is also better to update the packages particularly Microsoft `ASP.NET MVC` on Updates tab of Manage NuGet Packages.

Answer (score 0):

To install `System.Web.Mvc 3.0.0.0` version

1) Install [windows web platform installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)
2) Open Windows web platform installer from start menu
3) Go to `Products` tab
4) Search for MVC
5) Install MVC 3

[image]

Comment: The OP is using MVC4 - installing MVC3 wouild be rather counter-productive.

Answer (score -1):

In the error page I had this:

LOG: Redirection detected in the application configuration file: 5.1.0.0 was redirected to 5.2.3.0.

So I had to change this line in the web.config to the **5.1.0.0** version and it worked!

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
    <!--<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" /> Older line -->
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I think this is due to a version problem when I downloaded the code from TFS

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Add below code in web.config:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```