# EF code first Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

My MVC project was working, but now I get an error. That error occurs in my controller in my data layer (using Code First)

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.

This is the line causing the error:

```
var cultures = db.Cultures.Select(c => c.Code).ToArray();
```

In my mvc project I have deleted the data layer and added it again it again and then I set copy local to true but the error was not fixed.

My MVC project use System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0 and copy local is true
And Data layer use System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 and copy local is true

I looked error inner exception it give that error

```
   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Comment: Use Ben's technique in this answer to determine what DLL is causing your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l

Comment: Thank you @SteveGreene .I edited question.It Could not load System.Web.MVC.DLL

Comment: Seems like there are some issues with that assembly in MVC 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267006/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc

Comment: My MVC project version 4,the data layer which uses gac is use mvc version 3...error say it does not load version 3...so should I delete gac and install mvc 3 again?

Comment: Assuming you can't just update to 4.0? Try a binding redirect as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797015/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc-version-3-0-0-0-elmah-mvc-issu

Comment: this is very big project.I don't want workaround solution such as this <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>

Comment: there is no solution.So add denepdet assembly is best workaround solution..how can I mark your answear @SteveGreene

Comment: I would just up vote which ever link worked.